# Setting Image src to CDN URL

Tags: jquery, image, src

Here is what I am trying to do

I have a jQuery UI dialog with a large number of images like the ones below

```
<td><a id='ai42' class='ancico' title='Key'><img/></a></td>
<td><a id='ai52' class='ancico' title='Last'><img/></a></td>
<td><a id='ai62' class='ancico' title='Lock'><img/></a></td>
```

I want to avoid indicating a full CDN url for each image - results in several 100s of bytes of saving.  So what I am doing is this:

In the create: event for the dialog I do

```
$('.ancico').each(function(ndx,anc){adjustSourceTo(ndx,anc);});
```

The adjustSourceTo code goes like this

```
function adjustSourceTo(ndx,anc)
{
 var sources = new Array('noicon','alert','arrow-d','arrow-l','arrow-r','arrow-u','back',
 'check','delete','forward','gear','grid','home','info','minus','plus',
 'refresh','search','star','address','clock','email','ffwd','first','key',
 'last','lock','next','phone','prev','record','redo','rewind',
 'trolley','unlock')
  var isrc = sources[ndx];             
  var src = 'http://url_to_cdn/images/{src}.png'.format({src:isrc}); 
  console.log($(anc).attr('src',src).attr('src'));
 }
```

I can see that the URL being generated is correct and clicking on the log output takes me to the image.  However, when the dialog is opened the images remain stubbornly blank.  I thought this might be owing to my failure to specify a placeholder image for starters so I tried changing my HTML markup to

```
<img src='i.png'/>
```

but to no avail - now the anchors with their images turn up but are stuck with the i.png served up from my server rather than the real ones from the CDN.

The saving in app load will be significant if I can do this - I would be much obliged to anyone who might be able to tell me what I might be doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure there really is a performance boost? Especially if you send the requests gzipped any repetitive parts will be packed very efficiently.

Comment: But anyway, you're attaching the src attribute to the `<a>` tag, not the image. Change the selector to `$('.ancico img')`.

Comment: That was well spotted, I had completely forgotten that I am manipulating the parent anchor elements, not the images. - guess, I am just working too hard :-).  If you had given this as an answer I would have voted it up!

Comment: I forgot to mention - watching the traffic with Fiddler I have noted that if I in the CDN image sources in the markup the images get fetched  when the app loads up.  When I add then from script in the dialog create:event they get loaded when/if the user opens that dialog.  OK, with good CDN side chacheing this should not be a big deal either but I have set my heart on doing things a certain way so there is no point reasoning with me :-/